# Generating function for planted planar trees

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, generating-functions, trees

I need your help to solve this problem :

---

> Give a generating function for planted planar trees with all degrees odd.
>
> Show that the number of such trees with $2k+1$ non-root vertices is 
>   $$\displaystyle \frac{\binom{3k}{k}}{(2k+1)}$$

---

Please help !

Answer (score 4):

Start by  computing the generating  function for the odd  total degree
trees  without the  degree-one  root node.  There is an even number of children plus a link to the parent for a total odd degree. This  has the  functional
equation 
$$T(z) = z + z \frac{T(z)^2}{1-T(z)^2}.$$

Now recall the Lagrange Inversion Formula as presented e.g. at this
[MathWorld link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInversionTheorem.html)
(consulted May 26 2014.)

Using their variables we have $w=z$, $\alpha=z$ and
$$\phi(w) = \frac{w^2}{1-w^2}.$$

Setting $F(v) = v$ in the above we obtain
$$T(z) = z + \frac{z}{1} \frac{z^2}{1-z^2}
+ \frac{z^2}{2!} \frac{\partial}{\partial z} 
\left(\frac{z^2}{1-z^2}\right)^2
+ \frac{z^3}{3!} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2} 
\left(\frac{z^2}{1-z^2}\right)^3
+ \cdots.$$
Recall that
$$\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)^q
= \sum_{n\ge q} {n-1\choose q-1} z^n$$
so that
$$\left(\frac{z^2}{1-z^2}\right)^q
= \sum_{n\ge q} {n-1\choose q-1} z^{2n}.$$
This implies that
$$\frac{\partial^{q-1}}{\partial z^{q-1}} 
\left(\frac{z^2}{1-z^2}\right)^q
= \sum_{n\ge q} (2n)^{\underline{q-1}} 
{n-1\choose q-1} z^{2n-(q-1)}.$$
This in turn yields 
$$[z^m] \frac{z^q}{q!}\frac{\partial^{q-1}}{\partial z^{q-1}} 
\left(\frac{z^2}{1-z^2}\right)^q
\\= [z^m] \frac{z^q}{q!}
\sum_{n\ge q} (2n)^{\underline{q-1}} {n-1\choose q-1} z^{2n+1-q}
\\ = \frac{1}{q!} [z^{m-q}]
\sum_{n\ge q} (2n)^{\underline{q-1}} {n-1\choose q-1} z^{2n+1-q}.$$

If $m$ is odd this gives  $2n+1=m$ and we must have $(m-1)/2\ge q$ for
a contribution of
$$\frac{1}{q!} (m-1)^{\underline{q-1}}{m/2-3/2\choose q-1}.$$

Collecting everything into one formula  we obtain for $m\ge 3$ and $m$
odd the closed form 
$$1 + \sum_{q=2}^{m/2-1/2} \frac{1}{q!}
(m-1)^{\underline{q-1}}{m/2-3/2\choose q-1}$$
which is
$$1 + \sum_{q=2}^{m/2-1/2} \frac{1}{q!}
\frac{(m-1)!}{(m-q)!}
{m/2-3/2\choose q-1}$$
or equivalently
$$1 + \frac{1}{m}
\sum_{q=2}^{m/2-1/2} {m\choose q} {m/2-3/2\choose q-1}.$$

Simplifying this to
$$\frac{1}{m}{3m/2-3/2\choose m/2-1/2}$$
is best done with a CAS and Zeilberger's algorithm /
Sister Celine's method.

This is the following sequence
$$ 1, 3, 12, 55, 273, 1428, 7752, 43263, 246675, 1430715, \ldots$$
which is [OEIS A001764](http://oeis.org/A001764) where 
a variety of relevant information can be found.

**Addendum Tue May 27 22:12:28 CEST 2014.**

Here is some additional material  to document how to obtain the simple
closed form.

Note that we can absorb the term in front into the sum, turning
$$1 + \frac{1}{m}
\sum_{q=2}^{m/2-1/2} {m\choose q} {m/2-3/2\choose q-1}$$
into
$$\frac{1}{m}
\sum_{q=1}^{m/2-1/2} {m\choose q} {m/2-3/2\choose q-1}.$$
Now since $m$ is odd put $m=2k+1$ to get
$$\frac{1}{2k+1}
\sum_{q=1}^k {2k+1\choose q} {k-1\choose q-1}.$$

It turns out that Maple has an implementation of creative telescoping,
the method we cited above. In the present case it yields the following
data:

```
> restart;
> with(SumTools[DefiniteSum]):
> CreativeTelescoping(binomial(2*k+1,q)*binomial(k-1,q-1),q=1..k);
                       1/2   k
                      3    27  GAMMA(k + 1/3) GAMMA(k + 2/3)
                  1/2 --------------------------------------
                                Pi GAMMA(2 k + 1)
```

Now using the multiplication theorem of the
[Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)
we have that
$$\Gamma(k+1/3)\Gamma(k+2/3)
=\frac{2\pi\times 3^{1/2-3k}}{\Gamma(k)} \Gamma(3k).$$
Substituting this into the closed form for the sum yields
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}
\frac{3^{1/2+3k}}{\Gamma(2k+1)}
\frac{2\pi\times 3^{1/2-3k}}{\Gamma(k)} \Gamma(3k)
= \frac{3k\Gamma(3k)}{k\Gamma(k)\Gamma(2k+1)}.$$
It follows that the closed form for the number of trees is
$$\frac{1}{2k+1}
\frac{3k\Gamma(3k)}{k\Gamma(k)\Gamma(2k+1)}
= \frac{(3k)!}{(k!)\times (2k+1)!}
= \frac{1}{2k+1} \frac{(3k)!}{(k!)\times (2k)!}
= \frac{1}{2k+1} {3k\choose k}.$$

Note that the  method of creative telescoping provides  sound proof of
the closed forms  of the sums that it is applied to as explained e.g. by
Wilf in his book *generatingfunctionology*.

**Addendum Tue May 15 2018.** Starting from the functional equation

$$T(z) = z + z \frac{T(z)^2}{1-T(z)}$$

we may solve for $z$ to get

$$z = \frac{T(z)}{1/(1-T(z)^2)}$$

and we recognize that Lagrange-Burmann applies with

$$[z^m] T(z) = \frac{1}{m} [w^{m-1}] \frac{1}{(1-w^2)^m}.$$

With $m=2k+1$ this becomes

$$\frac{1}{2k+1} [w^{2k}] \frac{1}{(1-w^2)^{2k+1}}
= \frac{1}{2k+1} [w^{k}] \frac{1}{(1-w)^{2k+1}}
\\ = \frac{1}{2k+1} {2k+k\choose 2k} = \frac{1}{2k+1} {3k\choose 2k}.$$

This is the claim.

Concerning the evaluation of the sum form we find
that

$$\frac{1}{2k+1} \sum_{q=1}^k {2k+1\choose q} {k-1\choose k-q}
\\ = \frac{1}{2k+1} \sum_{q=1}^k {2k+1\choose q}
[z^{k-q}] (1+z)^{k-1}
\\ = \frac{1}{2k+1} [z^k] (1+z)^{k-1}
\sum_{q=1}^k {2k+1\choose q} z^q.$$

Now with  $k\ge 1$ we  may add  in the term  for $q=0$ with  no change
since $[z^k] (1+z)^{k-1} = 0.$ We may extend the upper limit to $2k+1$
as there  is no contribution  to the coefficient extractor  when $q\gt
k,$ getting

$$\frac{1}{2k+1} [z^k] (1+z)^{k-1}
\sum_{q=0}^{2k+1} {2k+1\choose q} z^q
= \frac{1}{2k+1} [z^k] (1+z)^{k-1} (1+z)^{2k+1}
= \frac{1}{2k+1} [z^k] (1+z)^{3k}
= \frac{1}{2k+1} {3k\choose k}.$$

This is the claim as before.

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me a lot even though I still do not understand all the steps.

Comment: Hi Marko Riedel,

I am new to this site, I would like to vote for you but I don't know how !

ALSO I WOULD LIKE TO SEND YOU A MESSAGE AND I DON?T FIND HOW TO JOIN YOU ! Hope you will see this

Comment: Thank you. I encourage you to learn more about this site and how it is used.

Comment: Please could you help me with this question :

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811821/generating-function-for-vertices-distance-from-the-root-in-a-planar-tree

Comment: Could you please give me more details how you get the first  the functional equation:
$$T(z) = z + z \frac{T(z)^2}{1-T(z)^2}.$$

I don't understand how you get this result. Please can you go step by step