# Generating function for vertices distance from the root in a planar tree

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, generating-functions, trees

I need you help to solve this problem:

---

> Consider a planar tree with $n$ non-root vertices.
>
> 1. Give a generating function for vertices distance $d$ from the root.
> 2. Proof that the total number is $$\displaystyle \binom{2n}{n-d}\frac{2d+1}{(n+d+1)}$$
>
> We are supposed to have an exponential generating function then use Lagrange Inversion Theorem...

---

Comment: How did you try to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

What  we want  here  is  ordinary generating  functions  since we  are
working  with  unlabeled  trees.  Start by  computing  the  generating
function $T_n(z)$ for  ordered planar trees of at  most a given height
$n$ classified according to the nodes  of a distance $d$ from the root
(variable $u_d$) and  the total number of nodes  (variable $z$), where
the singleton node has height zero, to get

$$T_0(z) = u_0 z \quad\text{and}\quad
T_n(z) = u_0 z + u_0 z \times 
\left.\frac{T_{n-1}(z)}{1-T_{n-1}(z)}
\right|_{u_0=u_1, u_1=u_2,\ldots}.$$

It then follows that the generating function $G_d(z)$ of the number of
nodes of a distance $d$ from  the root in all ordered planar graphs on
$n$ nodes is given by
$$G_d(z) = \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial v} 
T_d(z)(u_0=1, u_1=1, \ldots u_{d-1}=1, u_d = v\times Q(z)/z)
\right|_{v=1}.$$

Here  $Q(z)$  generates  ordered  trees  on  $n$  nodes  and  has  the
functional equation
$$Q(z) = z + z\frac{Q(z)}{1 - Q(z)}
= z \frac{1}{1-Q(z)}.$$
Re-write this as
$$Q(z) = z + Q(z)^2.$$

We use $Q(z)/z$ in the substitution because when we attach a tree at a
node  of depth  $d$ we  get  two overlapping  nodes, one  of which  we
remove.   Working with  this  we  discover that  it  encodes too  much
information.   There is  a closed  form of  $T_n(z)$ but  many of  its
properties can only be  conjectured, requiring considerable algebra to
prove. We see that we can in fact skip $T_d(z)$ and work directly with
a corresponding  generating function $F_d(z)$  where only leaves  of a
distance $d$ are marked and we do not need to shift markers from $u_f$
to  $u_{f+1}$  in the  recursive  step.   We  thus obtain  from  first
principles the recurrence

$$F_0(z) = vz \quad\text{and}\quad
F_d(z) = z + z \frac{F_{d-1}(z)}{1-F_{d-1}(z)}
= z \frac{1}{1-F_{d-1}(z)}.$$

We now claim that for $d\ge 2$ we have

$$F_d(z) = z\frac{(-1)^d P_{d-1}(z) + vz P_{d-2}(z)}
{P_d(z) - (-1)^d vz P_{d-1}(z)}$$

where     (these     are     closely     related     to     [Fibonacci
polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_polynomials))

$$P_d(z) = \begin{cases}
1 & \quad\text{if}\quad d=0 \\
-1 & \quad\text{if}\quad d=1 \\
(-1)^d P_{d-1}(z) + z P_{d-2}(z) & \quad\text{if}\quad d\ge 2.
\end{cases}$$

The proof  is by  induction. We have  by the  combinatorial recurrence
$F_1(z) = \frac{z}{1-vz}$ and hence $F_2(z) = z\frac{vz-1}{z-1+vz}.$
The formula in terms of the $P_d(z)$ yields

$$F_2(z) = z \frac{P_1(z)+vzP_0(z)}{P_2(z)-vzP_1(z)}
= z \frac{-1+vz}{z-1-vz\times -1}$$

and the base case holds. For the induction step we find

$$z \frac{1}{1-F_{d}(z)}
= z \frac{1}{1-z\frac{(-1)^d P_{d-1}(z) + vz P_{d-2}(z)}
{P_d(z) - (-1)^d vz P_{d-1}(z)}}
\\ = z \frac{P_d(z) - (-1)^d vz P_{d-1}(z)}
{P_d(z) - (-1)^d vz P_{d-1}(z)-z(-1)^d P_{d-1}(z) - vz^2 P_{d-2}(z)}
\\ = z \frac{P_d(z) - (-1)^d vz P_{d-1}(z)}
{P_d(z) - vzP_d(z) -z(-1)^d P_{d-1}(z)}
\\ = z \frac{(-1)^{d+1} P_d(z) + vz P_{d-1}(z)}
{(-1)^{d+1} P_d(z) - (-1)^{d+1} vzP_d(z) + z P_{d-1}(z)}
\\ = z \frac{(-1)^{d+1} P_d(z) + vz P_{d-1}(z)}
{P_{d+1}(z) - (-1)^{d+1} vzP_d(z)}.$$

This is the formula for $F_{d+1}(z)$ and the induction is complete.
We attach $Q(z)/z$ at $v$ as explained earlier to obtain

$$z\frac{(-1)^d P_{d-1}(z) + v Q(z) P_{d-2}(z)}
{P_d(z) - (-1)^d v Q(z) P_{d-1}(z)}.$$

Differentiating with respect to $v$ we get for the denominator

$$(P_d(z) - (-1)^d v Q(z) P_{d-1}(z))^2$$

and for the numerator (scalar $z$ will be restored at end)

$$Q(z) P_{d-2}(z) (P_d(z) - (-1)^d v Q(z) P_{d-1}(z))
\\ - ((-1)^d P_{d-1}(z) + v Q(z) P_{d-2}(z)) (-1)^{d+1} Q(z) P_{d-1}(z)
\\ = Q(z) P_d(z) P_{d-2}(z) + Q(z) P_{d-1}(z)^2.$$

We claim that

$$P_d(z) P_{d-2}(z) + P_{d-1}(z)^2 = z^{d-1}.$$

For an induction proof we get with $d=2$

$$(z-1) \times 1 + (-1)^2 = z$$

and the base case goes through. For the induction step we start
with

$$P_d(z) (P_d(z)/z - (-1)^d P_{d-1}(z)/z)  
+ P_{d-1}(z)^2  = z^{d-1}$$

or

$$P_d(z)^2 - (-1)^d P_{d-1}(z) P_d(z) + z P_{d-1}(z)^2 = z^d$$

which is

$$P_d(z)^2 + P_{d-1}(z)
((-1)^{d+1} P_d(z) + z P_{d-1}(z))
= P_d(z)^2 + P_{d-1}(z) P_{d+1}(z)$$

and the induction goes through. We have shown that

$$G_d(z) = \frac{z^{d} Q(z)}{(P_d(z) - (-1)^d Q(z) P_{d-1}(z))^2}.$$

We prepare  for Lagrange  Inversion to  conclude this  computation. We
have with $w=Q(z)$ that $z=w(1-w)$ and we now claim that

$$(P_d(w(1-w)) - (-1)^d w P_{d-1}(w(1-w)))^2 = (1-w)^{2d}.$$

Proof is by induction one more time. We have with $d=1$ that

$$(-1 - (-1) \times w \times 1)^2 = (-1+w)^2$$

and the  base case holds. For  the induction step re-write  the second
inner term on the LHS as

$$(-1)^{d+1} \frac{1}{1-w} (P_{d+1}(w(1-w)) -(-1)^{d+1} P_{d}(w(1-w)))$$

Add the first inner term to get

$$(-1)^{d+1} \frac{1}{1-w} (P_{d+1}(w(1-w)) -(-1)^{d+1} P_{d}(w(1-w))
\\ + (-1)^{d+1} P_d(w(1-w)) (1-w))
\\ = (-1)^{d+1} \frac{1}{1-w} (P_{d+1}(w(1-w)) 
+ (-1)^{d+1} P_d(w(1-w)) (-w)).$$

Square to get

$$\frac{1}{(1-w)^2} (P_{d+1}(w(1-w)) - (-1)^{d+1} w P_d(w(1-w)))^2.$$

This concludes the induction. For  Lagrange Inversion integral we thus
obtain

$$[z^m] G_d(z) = 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{m+1}} G_d(z) \; dz.$$

We have $dz = (1-2w) \; dw$ and  moreover $Q(z) = z + \cdots$ hence we
are justified in writing

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{m+1} (1-w)^{m+1}}
\frac{w^d (1-w)^d \times w}{(1-w)^{2d}}
(1-2w) \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{m-d} (1-w)^{m+1+d}} (1-2w) \; dw.$$

This evaluates by inspection to

$${m-d-1+m+d\choose m+d} - 2 {m-d-2+m+d\choose m+d}
\\ = {2m-1\choose m+d} - 2 {2m-2\choose m+d}.$$

OP asks for non-root vertices and thus $n=m-1$ and we find

$${2n+1\choose n+1+d} - 2 {2n\choose n+1+d}
\\ = \left(\frac{2n+1}{n+1+d}  - 2 \frac{n-d}{n+1+d} \right)
{2n\choose n+d}.$$

This is indeed

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{2d+1}{n+1+d} {2n\choose n-d}}$$

as claimed.

The relation to Fibonacci polynomials is readily apparent through
the fact that

$$P_d(z) = (-1)^{\lfloor (d+3)/2 \rfloor}
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor d/2 \rfloor}
{d-k\choose k} (-1)^{k+1} z^k$$

The proof  is again  by induction.   We immediately  get $P_0(z)  = -1
\times -  1 = 1$ and  $P_1(z) = 1 \times  -1 = -1$ for  the base case,
which  is correct.  The induction  step is  split into  a case-by-case
analysis modulo four, of which we  do one example, namely $d=4q+3.$ We
find

$$P_{4q+3}(z) = - P_{4q+2}(z) + z P_{4q+1}(z).$$

This becomes

$$- \sum_{k=0}^{2q+1}
{4q+3-k\choose k} (-1)^{k+1} z^k =
- \sum_{k=0}^{2q+1}
{4q+2-k\choose k} (-1)^{k+1} z^k
\\ + z \sum_{k=0}^{2q}
{4q+1-k\choose k} (-1)^{k+1} z^k$$

or

$$- \sum_{k=0}^{2q+1}
{4q+3-k\choose k} (-1)^{k+1} z^k =
- \sum_{k=0}^{2q+1}
{4q+2-k\choose k} (-1)^{k+1} z^k
\\ + \sum_{k=1}^{2q+1}
{4q+2-k\choose k-1} (-1)^{k} z^k.$$

This goes through as claimed since  the constant coefficient on $z$ is
minus one on both sides and for the coefficients on $[z^k]$ with $1\le
k\le 2q+1$ we get (attention to $(-1)^k$)

$$ - {4q+2-k\choose k} - {4q+2-k\choose k-1}
= {4q+3-k\choose k}
\left( - \frac{4q+3-2k}{4q+3-k} - \frac{k}{4q+3-k}  \right)
\\ = - {4q+3-k\choose k}.$$

To be  rigorous in the induction  we have to process  $4q+2, 4q+3, 4q$
and $4q+1$ in this order.

Another interesting fact that relates $P_d(z)$ to Fibonacci numbers is
that

$$P_d(-1) = (-1)^{\lfloor (d+1)/2 \rfloor} F_{d+1}.$$

Proof is a again by induction with the base case holding by inspection.
We then get from the recurrence on the RHS

$$(-1)^d (-1)^{\lfloor d/2 \rfloor} F_{d} 
- (-1)^{\lfloor (d-1)/2 \rfloor} F_{d-1}.$$

With  $d=2f$ the  coefficients on  the two  terms are  $(-1)^f =  (-1)
\times (-1)^{f-1} = (-1)^{\lfloor  (2f+1)/2\rfloor}$ and when $d=2f+1$
they  are $(-1)\times  (-1)^f  = (-1)  \times  (-1)^f =  (-1)^{\lfloor
(2f+2)/2\rfloor}$ and the claim is proven.